# unable to run step 3 of syspolicy_purge_history job on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, powershell

After installing an instance of SQL Server 2012 (SP3) on a server that had previously had SQL Server 2008R2 on it, I began encountering the following error while attempting to run step 3 of syspolicy_purge_history:

> A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The
>   corresponding line is 'import-module SQLPS  -DisableNameChecking'.
>   Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information
>   returned by PowerShell is: 'File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Sqlps.ps1 cannot be loaded
>   because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please
>   see "get-help about_signing" for more details. File C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Sqlps.ps1 cannot be loaded
>   because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please
>   see "get-help about_signing" for more details. '

I logged into the server as the SQL Server Agent account and ran the SQLPS executable directly as administrator. I saw that the Process scope was set to Restricted with all others Undefined. After changing group policy for the computer to RemoteSigned, the error changed to the following:

> A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The
>   corresponding line is 'set-executionpolicy restricted -scope process
>   -Force'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Security error. '

This occurs even after modifying the job so that it is simply running `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`. I've checked the registry tag and tried both deleting the registry key as well as changing it to Unrestricted and Bypass.

The only thing I haven't tried yet is attempting to upgrade the instances to 2014. It is a production box. Any suggestions other than disabling that step or running it using xp_cmdshell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look at this [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1739587/sqlps-exe-blocks-execution-of-powershell-scripts-and-loading-of-sqlps-modules-by-setting-executionpolicy-on-scope-process-to-restricted)

The SQL PowerShell wrapper SQLPS.EXE seems to execute a PS command `Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted -scope Process -Force` during its initialization. Then PS engine should then be initialized with command `import-module SQLPS  -DisableNameChecking` which is blocked because of the "Restricted" execution policy. This raises a critical error and the PowerShell engine terminates.

The workaround is adding/changing a registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps110]
"ExecutionPolicy"="RemoteSigned"
```

See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a85d4ea2-c80d-498a-aebc-26c3937fc964/syspolicypurgehistory-job-getting-failed-sql-server-2012?forum=sqltools) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4f4e5aa-71bf-48a7-bbd1-36de470c45c9/sql-powershell-sql-server-2014-does-not-start-because-of-insufficient-execution-policy?forum=sqltools) for additional reference.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! I had to add the key for Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps110 as well as the strings for Path and ExecutionPolicy, then changed the group policy to Undefined. At that point, the script ran perfectly!